# Battery indicator/upower not working since 22.10 upgrade

Tags: battery, indicator, 22.10

Since upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 a few days ago, the battery indicator doesn't work any more. It's stuck in whatever state it had at startup. Also, there's no warning message any more when the battery is getting low. (I've found that someone had the same problem years ago but they got no answer [[link]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590956/why-is-my-battery-indicator-stuck).)

I've reinstalled `gnome-power-manager` but that hasn't made any difference. I've also checked the battery level with `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1` and it seems to have the same issue as the battery indicator: it says the battery percentage is 99% even though that can't be true because the laptop has been unplugged for a while.

My computer is an ASUS TUF Gaming A15 (FA506II), if that's relevant.

Edit: I managed to solve the problem with the fix proposed by popey below. To blacklist `asus-ec-sensors`, I created the file `/etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf` and added the line `blacklist asus-ec-sensors`. (I hope that's the right way to do this.) After rebooting, the battery indicator is working again. Also, I found some more discussion of this topic [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216412) which might be interesting to some people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution today. It is because of Linux kernel 5.19.
You can fix it by blacklisting asus_ec_sensors.
Hopefully Ubuntu releases a kernel update soon.

Answer (score 0):

I  migrated to Ubuntu from Fedora yesterday. I had the same problem but was able to fix it by blacklisting asus_ec_sensors. Now I am having again on Ubuntu 22.10. Yesterday I tried 22.04 and it was fine. The issue lies in the kernel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have an ASUS TUF Gaming F15 (TUF506LH) and had the same problem: no update of the battery indicator and closing the lid didn't put the computer in sleep mode. I solved the problem by installing a more recent Linux Kernel (in my case 6.0.8), using [Mainline](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-linux-mainline-kernel-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/). After rebooting, the battery indicator was working correctly